# Android Wear Proguard

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-proguard

I tried using proguard with my Android Wear application, but I'm not sure what should be going into the rules. In my wear app's gradle file I have:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

and my `proguard-rules.pro` looks like:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

When I run my app, the UI works, but anything that accesses the `DataApi` is missing. Anyone have any ideas/experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by combining parts of [Firefox's proguard config](https://reviewboard.mozilla.org/r/1325/diff/2#index_header) with some of my own:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.android.gms.wearable.** {*;}

# Firefox
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
# Preserve all fundamental application classes.
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# Preserve enums. (For awful reasons, the runtime accesses them using introspection...)
-keepclassmembers enum * {
     *;
}
```